# Detect when a stylesheet is loaded twice

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm trying to debug my site in IE11 but it crashes when opening developer tools by F12.

Apparently this could be because of a CSS loading twice

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7115490/

How can I find which CSS causes the issue? I tried to look at the CSS resources loaded in Chrome in the Network tab, but there's no same css called twice. I am not sure it would even display it twice there.

Is there a tool or technique I can use?

Comment: don't you could simply look at the page source to detect style duplication? Do you load your stylesheet via javascript?

Comment: I tried to look but I couldn't find any duplicate, that's why I was looking for an easier way to find it. This really sucks. But now I wonder if a CSS duplicate is the actual cause.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to check if (IE or) your web page is loading duplicate CSS files:

1. Disable script debugging to prevent IE from crashing.
   `IE > Tools > Internet options > Advanced > Browsing > [X] Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)`
2. Press `F12` to open the Developer Tools window.
3. Click on the `Network` tab.
4. Filter traffic by CSS files.
   `Content type > [X] Style sheets`
5. Browse to or reload your web page and check to see if there are multiple CSS files loaded twice.